# How can I discover new MOOCs?

Tags: mooc

Back when platforms such as [edX](https://www.edx.org) were launching, every online course was new and exciting. Forums and mailing lists were active, and there was a strong sense of interaction with everyone involved.

Currently, plenty of the courses on these platforms are reruns of old courses—often converted to a "self-paced" format. The experience is simply not the same.

I don't see a filter for "premiere" courses on any of the major MOOC platforms. Is there a way to find out about new courses?

Comment: Many MOOCs are free unless you want certificates after taking them. You can't be too picky when you have free lunch, right?

Comment: I completely agree. Allow me to explain what prompted my question. Earlier this year, the [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/scala) specialization __launched__ on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org). I immediately shelled out $79, and was greeted by videos from 2012.

Comment: You can ask for [refund](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/scala) if you are not satisfied with it.

Comment: Have you tried using Class central? https://www.class-central.com/

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as off-topic, as this has little to do with academia or advanced education. MOOCs are a pretty broad topic.

Comment: Were the videos from 2012 technically obsolete? I am pretty confident people learn C++ from books decades old. Can't judge about Scala though.